# roscd stopped working

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just did:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libeigen3-dev
```

Afterwards roscd is not working anymore:

```
roscd kuka_arm
No command 'roscd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rosco' from package 'python-rosinstall' (universe)
roscd: command not found
```

Yes I sourced my workspace.
and I also did:

```
rosdep init
rosdep update
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

So I just also found out that ros-kinetic-cv-bridge requires libeigen3-dev. That is why if you do

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libeigen3-dev
```

cv-bridge will also be uninstalled. However all the packages I unfortunately also deleted when doing autoremove command above I could reinstall. But roscd is still not working...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305868/roscd-stopped-working/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2018-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscd` is part of `rosbash`. Can you check you have the Debian package `ros-kinetic-rosbash` still installed?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-10-15**:
Yap that was the reason ! Thanks ! :)